# Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iis, url-rewriting

I have a Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module running in IIS, I use to redirect request based on my custom logic.

It is based on this: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module

How can I access input header from my code?

Comment: Does `HttpContext.Current` have a value?

Comment: Rather than trying to consume that whole tutorial, can you breakdown what it is that you've tried and errors that you've received?

Comment: Just checked, it is null

Comment: I created an Inbound Rule, I defined the Match URL Pattern to /* so it captures any request.
Then in the Action Properties I've set 
{MyProvider: {here is my parameter}} I've tried X_REQUEST_HEADERNAME
But I'm getting an empty string in my Rewrite method
The method signature is
public string Rewrite(string value)

Comment: I've also tried passing {QUERY_STRING} and it works. My issue is that I cannot use  query string actually, the rule needs to be based on headers :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So found the answer, it uses a naming convention:

Server variables can also be used to access HTTP headers from the current request. Any HTTP header supplied by the current request is represented as a server variable that has a name generated in accordance to this naming convention:

All dash ("-") symbols in the HTTP header name are converted to underscore symbols ("*").
 All letters in the HTTP header name are converted to capital case.
 "HTTP*" prefix is added to the header name.

in my case, I ended up with something like this in my Action Properties \ Redirect URL:
{RoutingProvider: {QUERY_STRING}|{HTTP_ORGANISATIONID}}

HTTP_ORGANISATIONID is my custom header.

Thanks