# ISS Url Rewrite with Application Request Routing: Server Variables not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, arr

I have set a server variable to be available on my IIS server called COUNTRY_PATH

I am doing a Reverse Proxy rewrite from one site to another and need to access this server variable in my proxied site. However it never seems to have a value.

```
<rule name="Country Codes For DotCom" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([A-Z]{2,2})(/)(microsite)(.*)" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="\.com$" />
     </conditions>
     <serverVariables>
          <set name="COUNTRY_PATH" value="{R:1}{R:2}{R:3}" />
     </serverVariables>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="http://internal.example.com/{R:1}{R:2}{R:3}{R:4}" />
</rule>
```

Are Server Variables available for reverse proxy?

I am using the following code to get the server variable:

```
string countryPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["COUNTRY_PATH"]
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Another user had a similar issue implementing a rewrite provider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900415/custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix your server variable with "HTTP_" when you add it to the allowed server variables and when you reference it in your rewrite serverVariable element. An easy way to confirm you have done so correctly is by using the builtin type down functionality, enter {H and then select {HTTP_COUNTRY_PATH} from the available options.

For a full explanation please read the following section of the article below: USING INBOUND REWRITE RULES TO SET REQUEST HEADERS AND SERVER VARIABLES

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is the case. I've used server variables that aren't prefixed with HTTP before. As discussed in this article on IIS.net where they set a server variable called ORIGINAL_URI: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, that is the exact article that bit me in the backside when I was creating a new server variable for the first time. I was on my mobile when I posted, I have now added a reference to support my answer.

Comment: One further comment: If you don't use it already, Failed Request Tracing if your friend.